# Singularity at $z=0$ for $1-\cos(z)\sin(\frac{1}{z})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, contest-math

Any ideas for solving this problem, mentioned in our last exam, is highly appreciated.

What is the residue of $f(z)=(1-\cos z)\sin \frac{1}{z}$ at the isolated point $z=0$ ?

Our notes say the answer is: $ - \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n!} \frac {1}{(n+1)!}  $

```
what is the step that reach to above solution?
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take the Maclaurin series for $\sin(x)$ and then replace $x$ with $1/z$. Then take the Maclaurin series for $\cos(x)$ and replace $x$ with $z$. Then do some arithmetic with these to find all terms of order $-1$ in the Laurent series expansion of $(1-\cos z)\sin \frac{1}{z}$ at $z=0$.

Comment: @LoveMathContest say your series for $\sin$ is $f(x)$, and your series for $\cos$ is $g(x)$. Then compute the coefficient on the $x^{-1}$ term in $(1-g(z))f(1/z))$, which you can do by some basic algebra. The residue, as you should know, is this coefficient.

Comment: Woluld you please add more detail? I do lot's of effort but get stuck in it.